# CakePhp print if controller & function is not

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to write an if statement to put into a CakePhp template.

Basically I want to print a piece of code on all pages except 1. This page is generated when the controller is "user" and the function "page" in that controller is executed.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->meta('icon');

    echo $this->Html->script(array('jqueryTouchSwipe.min', 'custom'));

    if($this->params['controller'] != 'users'){
        echo $this->Html->script('jquery.onp.sociallocker.1.7.6.min');
        echo $this->Html->script('box');
    }

    echo $this->fetch('meta');
    echo $this->fetch('script');
?>
```

However, this only accounts for the controller not being users but does not account for the function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `$this->params['action']` like:-

```
if ($this->params['controller'] !== 'users' && $this->params['action'] !== 'page') {
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery.onp.sociallocker.1.7.6.min');
    echo $this->Html->script('box');
}
```